# How to drilldown data from Invoke-webrequest content result?

Tags: powershell, invoke-webrequest

I managed to return the content of invoke-webrequest in the form of string but now I am out of idea to access the individual value inside since it is string value.

This is a snippet of the returned string, I omit some part of the value

```
{
  "odata.metadata":"https://wdzbomfg1.com/api/odata/v3/$metadata#report_description","odata.count":"18
80","value":[
    {
      "ActivityInstanceDestinationID":"20","ActivityName":"Task","ActivityInstan
ceID":"18","ProcessInstanceID":"1223","Destination":"a2\\","StartDate
":"2021-05-10T18:47:01","FinishDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","Status":"Active","Du
ration":"0","ProcessName":"ReviewSub","ProcessFolder":"Work","Fol
io":"","ExpectedDuration":"0","ActivityID":"","Final_Acti
on":null,"ActivityDisplayName":"Task"
    }
  ],"odata.nextLink":"https://wdzbomfg1.com/api/odata/v3/$metadata#report_description?$filter=StartDate%20ge%20d
atetime'2021-05-10T13:40:08'&$skip=1000"
}
```

I already tried to convert it to json but it convert everything into a single value inside odata.metadata . All I want is to be able to access it like an array for example $var.odata.count will output 1880.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Json = @'
{
  "odata.metadata":"https://wdzbomfg1.com/api/odata/v3/$metadata#report_description","odata.count":"18
80","value":[
    {
      "ActivityInstanceDestinationID":"20","ActivityName":"Task","ActivityInstan
ceID":"18","ProcessInstanceID":"1223","Destination":"a2\\","StartDate
":"2021-05-10T18:47:01","FinishDate":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","Status":"Active","Du
ration":"0","ProcessName":"ReviewSub","ProcessFolder":"Work","Fol
io":"","ExpectedDuration":"0","ActivityID":"","Final_Acti
on":null,"ActivityDisplayName":"Task"
    }
  ],"odata.nextLink":"https://wdzbomfg1.com/api/odata/v3/$metadata#report_description?$filter=StartDate%20ge%20d
atetime'2021-05-10T13:40:08'&$skip=1000"
}
'@
```

```
$Object = ConvertFrom-Json $Json
$Object.'odata.count'
18
80
```

[`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) deserializes the `$Json` string where the `'odata.count'` contains the requested value.

<sub>Note that in your example the value `1880` is split by a newline with outputs the value `18` and `80` on different lines.</sub>

Comment: I tried your solution but it always throws invalid JSON primitive: .

Comment: Apparently it was a silly mistake from my side. I have marked your answer as the solution. Thank you